# How to make a sum for two queries in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I need a concrete answer, thank you. I have this php code and query, as well as the table. What actually works here, in this query, values are added from the row, but it is not taken into account if they have a value of 0. It is necessary: to do this query, but also to get the values obtained and to divide the number of rows from the column depending on how they are entered:

**EXAMPLE**:

```
(4.20 + 5.00 + 4.80) / 3 number of rows = 4,67 TOTAL or

(4.20 + 5.00 + 4.80 + 3,10 + 5,00) / 5 number of rows = 4,42 TOTAL etc.
```

Sum of all rows divided by number of rows:

```
CREATE TABLE `ocene` 
(
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `predmeti` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `ocena1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `ocena2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `ocena3` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `ocena4` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `ocena5` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `ocena6` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `ocene` (`id`, `predmeti`, `ocena1`, `ocena2`, `ocena3`, `ocena4`, `ocena5`, `ocena6`) 
VALUES (1, 'French', '4', '5', '5', '5', '5', '0'),
       (2, 'Mathematics', '3', '5', '3', '2', '5', '5'),
       (3, 'English', '5', '5', '5', '0', '0', '0'),
       (4, 'Physics', '5', '3', '5', '4', '0', '0'),
       (5, 'Chemistry', '4', '4', '5', '4', '2', '0');
```

My php code:

```
    $sql = "SELECT predmeti, 
    ROUND((ocena1 + ocena2 + ocena3 + ocena4 + ocena5 + ocena6) /
          ((ocena1 != '0') + (ocena2 != '0') + (ocena3 != '0') + (ocena4 != '0') + (ocena5 != '0') + (ocena6 != '0')), 2) 
          AS final_count
    FROM ocene";

    if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
      {
      printf ("%s = <b>%s</b> <br />",$row[0],$row[1]);
      }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
  }
```

The current result is:

```
French = 4,80
Mathematics = 3,83
English = 5,00
Physics = 4,25
Chemistry = 3,80
```

I need the following:

```
    French = 4,80
    Mathematics = 3,83
    English = 5,00
    Physics = 4,25
    Chemistry = 3,80
    ----------
    TOTAL: 4,34 <--- sum of all rows divided by number of rows
```

Comment: perhaps https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and ideally should not be used in new code.

Comment: Please, is there any concrete answer?

Comment: Probably the first thing you need to fix is your database table.

Comment: My table works without error! There's no need for that.

Comment: use the mysqli_num_rows in order to know total number of rows.https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_num_rows.asp

Comment: First I need to sum all the rows for `final_count` and only after that to devide with the number of rows. Take a look at my example at the beginning of the question.

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try if a GROUP BY with an average and a WITH ROLLUP works for your version of MySql.

If each "predmeti" has only 1 record? Then it should be OK, since an AVG of 1 value equals the value.

```
SELECT COALESCE(predmeti, 'TOTAL') AS  predmeti, 
 ROUND(AVG((ocena1 + ocena2 + ocena3 + ocena4 + ocena5 + ocena6) / ((ocena1 != '0') + (ocena2 != '0') + (ocena3 != '0') + (ocena4 != '0') + (ocena5 != '0') + (ocena6 != '0'))),2) AS final_count
FROM ocene
GROUP BY predmeti WITH ROLLUP
```

**Result:**

```
predmeti    final_count
----------  --------------
Chemistry   3,8
English     5
French      4,8
Mathematics 3,83
Physics     4,25
TOTAL       4,34
```

Comment: Don't know. Replace the SQL in the php and try?

Comment: Btw, most people would use a numeric data type to keep numbers.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT ROUND( sum( 
    ROUND((ocena1 + ocena2 + ocena3 + ocena4 + ocena5 + ocena6) /
          ((ocena1 != '0') + (ocena2 != '0') + (ocena3 != '0') + (ocena4 != '0') + (ocena5 != '0') + (ocena6 != '0')), 2) 
          ) / COUNT(id), 2) as Total
    FROM ocene